# Install with ./configure with yum

Tags: centos, yum

I want to install squid on my CentOS 7 and I noticed I have two options. Either I can get it with `yum`, or I can download and untar it.

In the tar method I can add `./configure` to my make file and then install it as desired, but I was wondering if the same method can be applied to a direct `yum` install.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is very much the point of using a package manager like `yum`. That you get pre-compiled programs without having to configure and worry about dependencies.